# How to Convert ListView to Datatable in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, datatable

How to convert `ListView` to `DataTable`?

`XAML`

```
<ListView x:Name="listViewUserHUD" ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionUserData}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" util:GridViewSort.AutoSort="True" Margin="16,59,15,61">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FileNumber}" Header="FileNumber" Width="125" util:GridViewSort.PropertyName="FileNumber"  />
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ShiftDate}" Header="ShiftDate" Width="125" util:GridViewSort.PropertyName="ShiftDate"/>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding TimeCreated}" Header="TimeCreated" Width="125" util:GridViewSort.PropertyName="TimeCreated" />
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Remarks}" Header="Remarks" Width="350" util:GridViewSort.PropertyName="Remarks" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Code *not* working:

```
var listView1 = new ListView();

DataTable table = new DataTable();

foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
{
    table.Columns.Add(item.ToString());
    foreach (var it in item.SubItems)
    table.Rows.Add(it.ToString());
}
```

This is the code I have now, but I'm trying do is. How can I convert `ListView` to `DataTable` every time when I generate an items on `ListView`?

Comment: What is `CollectionUserData`?

Comment: a collection from my sqlite database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to create the table right form your data source object:

```
// Create the `DataTable` structure according to your data source
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("FileNumber", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("ShiftDate", typeof(DateTime));
table.Columns.Add("TimeCreated", typeof(DateTime));
table.Columns.Add("Remarks", typeof(string));

// Iterate through data source object and fill the table
foreach (var item in CollectionUserData)
{
    table.Rows.Add(item.FileNumber, item.ShiftDate, item.TimeCreated, item.Remarks);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var table = listViewUserHUD.DataSource as DataTable
```

Comment: This won't work since `ListView` doesn't have any `DataSource` DP.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var table = List_bill.DataContext as DataTable;
```